# Binomial distribution with weights but constant probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

What is the name of the distribution and/or distribution function of random variable $X$?

$X=a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2+...+a_n x_n$

$x_1, ..., x_n$ are independent binomial variables (Bernoulli). $x_i=1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ else. $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are given deterministic integers (weights) $\geq 1$.

**How do I show that $P(X>\frac{1}{2}\sum a_i)+\frac{1}{2}P(X=\frac{1}{2}\sum a_i) \geq p$ for $p \geq \frac{1}{2}$?**

This is not a Poisson binomial distribution. It is a generalized Poisson binomial but with the nice property that $p$ is constant. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277330/weighted-poisson-binomial-distribution) gives an almost identical problem.

In the spirit of the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262426/what-is-cumulative-distribution-function-of-this-random-variable) I can calculate probabilities as $P(s_k)=(1-p)^n \sum_{i_1,...,i_m |\sum a_{i_k}=s_k} \Bigl( \frac{p}{1-p}\Bigr)^{\sum i_k}$. However, this does not seem to get me closer to the proof.

It might also be possible to cleverly get the desired proof without a complete distribution function.